# Q: Lyapunov Exponents for Discontinous Systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

I'm attempting to characterize the chaotic nature of orbits for a dynamical system I'm studying. I've implemented some code which calculates the entire spectrum of Lyapunov exponents and works well for known systems like the Lorenz and Rossler systems. However, I'm not sure if it would apply for my dynamical system which has discontinuities in it. From my reading, it seems like Lyapunov exponents apply for smooth systems (from Oseledets theorem I believe). Do you know of any research or papers that describe if Lyapunov exponents can be used to characterize chaos for systems with discontinuities?

For some context, my system involves a free magnetic sphere making elastic collisions with a fixed sphere, and the discontinuities are from those collisions. I've used the code I've written to find Lyapunov exponents, but in looking at trajectories for stable states and unstable states (found from a previous research [paper](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5125924)) the Lyapunov exponents seems to not describe the chaotic nature of those states very well.

Comment: The main reference is A. Katok and J.-M. Strelcyn, Invariant Manifolds, Entropy and Billiards; Smooth Maps with Singularities, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol. 1222, Springer, 1986. The word "Smooth" should not be a discouragement, since as in your case the only singularities come from collisions. The only matter is that perhaps the exposition is somewhat heavy, it needs to be digested, but in my opinion it should be rewarding.

Comment: PS: The usual approach is to consider only the dynamics with discrete time taken at the collision times, and so consider the Lyapunov exponents for discrete time, which is also standard in the theory.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks for the reference! As for "discrete time" do you just mean changing the flow to a time-t map?

Comment: Not time $t$, you discretize at the times of collision, like in a Poincaré section or the hitting times on a billiard. The trajectory is "free" outside the collisions (may have forces acting). A somewhat more amenable reference is https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/ergodic-theory-and-dynamical-systems/article/infinitesimal-lyapunov-functions-invariant-cone-families-and-stochastic-properties-of-smooth-dyanmical-systems/32F9FB8599C0EE22F35E8DFE2794DFC1 where the correspondence to what I'm saying is to consider the return time (in your case return time to the surface of the fixed sphere).

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks for the clarification.